# Translate transformation applied while only scale transformation added

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am creating an animation that I want to use when the app is retrieving some data online. The idea is that I have some dots in a row, they will be scaled smaller that their original sizes then return to their original size and all of this with a small delay between each scaling. The animation is repeated and use auto-reverse mode.

To do that I create some dots using a core graphic method, add them to a view and position them using a `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` transformation. Then I use a loop to animate them one by one with a delay and I use a `CGAffineTransformScale` transformation for scaling.

Problem: I don't get the expected animation (at least what I'm expecting). When the dots are being scaled, they also move back to their original position.

Can someone enlighten me why there is a translate transformation while in the `UIView` animation, I'm only specifying a scaling?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
private var dots = [UIImage]()

public init(numberOfDots: Int, hexaColor: Int, dotDiameter: CGFloat = 30, animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1) {
    self.dotDiameter = dotDiameter
    self.animationDuration = animationDuration

    for _ in 0 ..< numberOfDots {
        dots.append(GraphicHelper.drawDisk(hexaColor, rectForDisk: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dotDiameter, height: dotDiameter), withStroke: false))
    }

    let spaceBetweenDisks: CGFloat = dotDiameter / 3
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(numberOfDots) * dotDiameter + CGFloat(numberOfDots - 1) * spaceBetweenDisks
    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, dotDiameter))

    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    for (i, dot) in dots.enumerate() {
        let dotImageView = UIImageView(image: dot)

        addSubview(dotImageView)

        let spaceBetweenDisks: CGFloat = dotDiameter / 3
        let xOffset = CGFloat(i) * (dotDiameter + spaceBetweenDisks)

        dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffset, 0)
    }
}

public func startAnimation() {
    for i in 0 ..< self.dots.count {
        let dotImageView: UIImageView = self.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
        let transformBeforeAnimation = dotImageView.transform

        let delay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(i)/NSTimeInterval(self.dots.count) * animationDuration

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: delay, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {

            dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(dotImageView.transform, 0.05, 0.05)

            }, completion: { finished in
                dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                dotImageView.transform = transformBeforeAnimation
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I found a fix but I don't understand how come it's fixing it. So if anyone can explain.

I added these 2 lines:

```
dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
dotImageView.transform = transformBeforeAnimation
```

before this line in `startAnimation`:

```
dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(dotImageView.transform, 0.05, 0.05)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining translate and scale transforms is confusing and hard to get right.

I have to spend far too much time with graph paper and deep thought in order to figure it out, and I'm too tired for that right now.

Don't do that. Place your dot image views by moving their center coordinates, and leave the transform at identity. Then when you scale them they should scale in place like you want.

Note that if you want them to move and scale at the same time you can both alter the view's center property and it's transform scale in the same animateWithDuration call and it works correctly. (Not so with changing the frame by the way. If you change the transform then the frame property doesn't work correctly any more. Apple's docs say that the results of reading/writing the frame property of a view with a non-identity transform are "undefined".)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its going back to its original position and not scaling based on the original center point instead? Try changing the order of applying transforms by doing this:

```
public func startAnimation() {
    for i in 0 ..< self.dots.count {
        let dotImageView: UIImageView = self.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
        let transformBeforeAnimation = dotImageView.transform

        let delay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(i)/NSTimeInterval(self.dots.count) * animationDuration

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: delay, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {
            // make scale transform separately and concat the two
            let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
            dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformBeforeAnimation, scaleTransform)

            }, completion: { finished in
                dotImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                dotImageView.transform = transformBeforeAnimation
        })
    }
}
```

From apple docs:

> Note that matrix operations are not commutative—the order in which you concatenate matrices is important. That is, the result of multiplying matrix t1 by matrix t2 does not necessarily equal the result of multiplying matrix t2 by matrix t1.

So, keep in mind that assigning a transformation creates a new affine transformation matrix, and concatenation will modify the existing matrix with the new one - the order you apply these in can create different results.

To make this work, I also updated the value of your translation on `dotImageView`. It needs to be `requiredTranslation / scale`.. if applying the translation before the scale. So in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
dotImageViewtransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1000, 0)
```

And then the animation:

```
// make scale transform separately and concat the two
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
self.card.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformBeforeAnimation, scaleTransform)
```

Comment: I made the changes, it's still the same problem. Regarding your question I am not sure. But from what I see on the animation I would say it's going back first to its original position and moving (with animation) to it's current position while scaling. I actually found a way to make it right but I don't understand it, I found it after toying for a while with different transforms. I'm editing the question.

Comment: So yea the problem is you're trying to do everything with affine transformations. I'd probably set up the frames without a translation transform, and only scale them. If you want to do it all with affine transforms, think about how the concatenation works. If you apply the transform and then the scale, you need to divide the transform by the scale to calculate the value of your offset. Keep in mind that "a transform" is the result of multiplying all the transform matrices you applied.

Comment: I updated my answer with this better info. Tested and works as expected, without the extra transform assignments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to do the opposite animation by scaling first to  0.05 and then by 1/0.05 in the animation closure but it didn't work as expected so I ended up not using a translate to move my views at first, I just changed the center and applied a transform only for scaling.

Comment: Opposite animation would just be accomplished with CGAffineTransformIdentity - that would bring it back to no transform.